# how can I find the limit superior and limit inferior of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

The sequence is $a_n = (-1)^n +2/n, \quad  n =1,2,3,...$ and $A= \left\{a_n : n=1,2,3,...\right\}$. The questions are :
$i)$ to calculate the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$sup $ a_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}$inf $ a_n$ 
$ii)$ Determine the limit points of A. 
$iii)$ Is A open? Why? 
$iv)$ Is A closed? Why? 
$v)$ Has A any isolated points? If so which?
$vi)$Determine $\overline A$.

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: We might appreciate seeing what you have tried and where you are stuck in order to help you

Comment: I dont even know where to start since im reading the definition and getting nowhere. So if you could kindly help me answer them by explaining how to think.

Comment: @davidharun: You can start with writing first few terms of sequences $\sup a_n$ and $\inf a_n.$ Then see if they are convergent or not. This is basically the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as written in i).